# Dynamically change some part of URL with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML code

```
 <img src="YP.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" onclick="location.href =&#39;phonepe://pay?pn=Phonepe Pvt Ltd&amp;pa=ktb.xkhemkaryt05322@icici&amp;tn=Order&amp;am=200&#39;;">
```

And I want to convert specific part of URL by just converting the letters to uppercase in a series.

"ktb.xkhemkaryt05322" This is the part which I want to dynamically change (Just uppercase in a series, like uppercase 1 letter at a time only)

I am not a developer but I am struggling to be one. Anyone kind enough to provide me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic url assaign into this (`dynamicUrl`) variabel

Example:

```
var dynamicUrl = "/terget/url"

<img src="YP.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" onclick="location.href =&#39;phonepe://pay?pn=Phonepe Pvt Ltd&amp;pa=${dynamicUrl}">
```

Comment: So if I use this ${dynamicUrl), i can change this to my custom string with JS?

Comment: The target URL you  have to assign first in this variable, we assume that  the target URL is `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions"` then you need to assign this URL in a variable, Like `var dynamicUrl =  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" `